# Обращение к git-dir через work-tree без симлинка

Tags: git, macos, dropbox

Есть `~/work/project` и `~/Dropbox/`, в котором project → `~/work/project`.

В самом `~/work/project` папка `.git` вынесена в `~/work/project-git`

Так вот, как без создания симлинка можно по прежнему вызывать git в `~/work/project`?

Симлинк использовать нельзя так как дропбокс скопирует все содержимое. Может, ему можно как-то сказать не делать этого?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

адресоваться к каталогу с хранилищем (если он находится не в каталоге `.git` в корне проекта) можно разными способами.

в вашем случае подойдёт адресация с помощью файла `.git`, описанная, например, в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8603156/4827341).

---

покажу на примере:

- рабочую копию (*workdir*) вы хотите держать в каталоге `/путь/к/проекту`
- а само хранилище (*gitdir*) хотите держать в каталоге `/путь/к/хранилищу`

1. сделайте текущим каталог `/путь/к/проекту`:

   ```
   $ cd /путь/к/проекту
   ```
2. инициализируйте хранилище:

   - для программы *git* версии **1.7.5 или выше**:

     ```
     $ git --separate-git-dir /путь/к/хранилищу init
     ```

     в каталоге `/путь/к/хранилищу` будет создано полноценное хранилище со всеми необходимыми файлами/каталогами: `branches`, `config`, `description` и т.д., а в **текущем** каталоге будет создан **файл** `.git` с «отсылкой» к месторасположению хранилища, такого содержания:

     ```
     gitdir: /путь/к/хранилищу
     ```
   - для программы *git* версии **ниже 1.7.5** надо будет проделать описанное в полу-ручном режиме:

     ```
     $ git --git-dir=/путь/к/хранилищу --work-tree=. init
     $ echo "gitdir: /путь/к/хранилищу" > .git
     ```

---

### для случая, если хранилище уже существует в каталоге `.git` в корне вашего проекта, потребуются такие действия:

1. сделайте текущим каталог `/путь/к/проекту`

   ```
   $ cd /путь/к/проекту
   ```
2. установите явно в конфигурации хранилища путь к рабочему каталогу:

   ```
   $ git config core.worktree /путь/к/проекту
   ```
3. переместите каталог `.git` в нужное место с нужным именем (целевой каталог `/путь/к/хранилищу` не должен существовать в этот момент, иначе файлы/каталоги хранилища попадут в `/путь/к/хранилищу/.git`):

   ```
   $ mv .git /путь/к/хранилищу
   ```
4. создайте файл `.git` в текущем каталоге:

   ```
   $ echo "gitdir: /путь/к/хранилищу" > .git
   ```